# Exclude updated record from trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column named priority.  I created a trigger function that fires after update.  I want the function to change the values of the rest of the rows' priority column.  For example I have 10 rows and each row has a single value ranging from 1-10, I then want to change the priority of row 10 to 1, then add 1 to the rest of the rows.

I've tried to change the query in many ways and add more/less logic to the function, but I am stuck.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION reorder_priority() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    CASE TG_OP
        WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN
            UPDATE
                link
            SET
                priority = priority + 1
            WHERE
                link.priority >= NEW.priority AND
                NOT link.priority > OLD.priority;
    END CASE;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function was able to do this, but it seems to trigger twice, adding 1 to every single row again, leaving me with 10 rows, but priority ranging from 2-11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out..

Just had to change the comparison to exclude updating the value of OLD.priority, return NEW, and also change the trigger to run BEFORE and not AFTER

```sql
BEGIN
    CASE TG_OP
        WHEN 'UPDATE' THEN
            UPDATE
                link
            SET
                priority = priority + 1
            WHERE
                link.priority >= NEW.priority AND
                NOT link.priority >= OLD.priority;
    END CASE;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
```